# Node Module Dependency Management with Continues Integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, dependency-management

I have 11 different node modules that have dependencies on each other. We release our code to production on a 2 week sprint cycle. With each release we must go into each module and manually update the dependency versions. My question is, is there a more automated way to update these dependency versions so we could ideally create a button that would create our release for us?

Example:

- Module: A Version 1.0.3
- Module: B 1.2.1 - A 1.0.3
- Module: C 1.1.0- A 1.0.3, B 1.2.1
- Module: D 1.0.3 - A 1.0.3, C 1.0.3

Currently I must update the package.json for each of my dependencies manually. I release all 4 modules at the same time. Is there a way to automate this update process?

Comment: checkout `npm version ...` https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/version

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I have found that this can be accomplished with the npm plugin lerna.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/lerna

This will allow you to keep all your node modules in a mono repo project and keep the versions in sync with automated tools. This is used by big projects such as babel. It is very easy to setup and use.